# cannot boot into recovery after reinstalling Big Sur

Tags: macos, recovery

MBP Intel,cannot boot into recovery after reinstalling Big Sur.
I had to reinstall Big Sur and after that I could not boot into recovery mode.
I can however boot into internet recovery (command/ shift/R)
Has anyone an advise for me please?

Comment: Internet Recovery and (local) recovery is basically the same thing.  Why are you trying to boot to recovery after a successful reinstall of Big Sur? What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Local recovery got corrupted (on your hard disk), use Internet recovery to remedy

Comment: thx for the reply.

Comment: local recovery is NOT the same as internet recovery. Further recovery is not corrupted. I have reinstalled 2 times. your question is not helpful but thanks anyways.

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved the issue as follows:
I erased the Recovery volume and reinstalled Big Sur

Problem solved